# Evince keep position like xdvi

Tags: pdf, viewers, evince

One feature I miss from the dvi days is the ability to keep position from page to page that xdvi has,

> -keep (.keepPosition) Sets a flag to indicate that xdvi should not
>         move to the home position when moving to a new page.  See also the
>         `k' keystroke. This flag is honored by all page switching actions and
>         by up-or-previous() / down-or-next(), although the latter only honor
>         the horizontal postion, not the vertical one.  This allows for a
>         "continuous" scrolling back an forth through a document with a
>         display window narrower than a page width.

I can find no equivalent in Evince (or other PDF viewer). Is there any such feature, and if so, how do I invoke it?

Added: I found [this feature request](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evince-list/2007-March/msg00025.html) which is basically asking for the same thing. It is apparently unanswered.

Comment: Rephrased, this might be better somewhere like SuperUser (it's about PDF viewers in general). As it stands I suspect they'll reject a migration, though.